# Grid areas on safari does not appear to work

Tags: google-chrome, safari, css-grid

I have been developing a largish single page application that will be running on a local lan - ie not open to the public.  That has to support the Chrome browser and iPads.

I've got large sections working on Chrome, but I ran across a problem with an iPad with the following section (this full app is made of web components - I've tried to make a fairly minimal test case.

In the scenario - in Chrome (78) the two date input fields are positioned at the top of a "menu card" in the second quarter in - below that is 16 buttons in a 4 x 4 grid.

The problem is - the same page in Safari (on my Mac (v13.0.3) and on my iPad - running IOS 13.1.3) displays all the  components of the grid one over the other. There is a small difference between the Mac, and the iPad.  On the latter the dates fields appear to actually be taller than the rest, whereas on the Mac the are entirely hidden.

I've searched for differences between chrome and safari and I can not find any.

Have I got the syntax of the CSS wrong? and then Chrome accepts it and Safari doesn't?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>Grid Issue</title>

    <base href="/concepts/">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x32" href="../images/pas-icon-32.png">

    <style>
      html {
        background: #ffffff;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 100vh;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        color: #333;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
      <style>
        :root {
          --pas-button-menu-height: 70px;
          --pas-button-menu-width:  225px;
        }

        .menu-card {
          grid-template-rows: auto repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--pas-menu-button-height), max-content));
        }

        .three {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(4,var(--pas-menu-button-width));
          grid-template-areas:
            ". selector . ."
            "covstat covstatnotx surgstat treat"
            "enqstats embassy notreat surgpay"
            "surgnopre prebook pricebreak bookstats"
            "bookfirst bookclinic bookappt bookdet";
        }
        .selectors {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }

        .three .selectors {
          grid-area: selector;
        }
        #covstat_portrait {
          grid-area: covstat;
        }
        #covstatnotx_portrait {
          grid-area: covstatnotx;
        }
        #surgstat_portrait {
          grid-area:surgstat;
        }
        #treat {
          grid-area: treat;
        }
        #enqstats {
          grid-area: enqstats;
        }
        #embassy {
          grid-area: embassy;
        }
        #notreat {
          grid-area: notreat;
        }
        #surgpay {
          grid-area: surgpay
        }
        #surgnopre {
          grid-area: surgnopre;
        }
        #prebook {
          grid-area: prebook;
        }
        #pricebreak {
          grid-area: pricebreak;
        }
        #bookstats {
          grid-area: bookstats;
        }
        #bookfirst {
          grid-area: bookfirst;
        }
        #bookclinic {
          grid-area: bookclinic;
        }
        #bookappt {
          grid-area: bookappt;
        }
        #bookdet {
          grid-area: bookdet;
        }
        section.menu-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
        }
        section.menu-container > .menu-card {
          margin: 40px 0 20px 0;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            background-color: white;
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 30px;

        }
      </style>
      <section class="menu-container">
          <div class="menu-card three">

              <div class="selectors">
                <input id="startdate" type="date" label="Start Date" .value="1/11/2019"></input>
                <input id="enddate" type="date"label="End Date" .value="30/11/2019" ></input>
              </div>


              <button id="covstat_portrait" >Conversion Statistics</button>
              <button id="covstatnotx_portrait">Conversion Statistics (inc No Tx)</button>
              <button id="surgstat_portrait">Surgery Statistics</button>
              <button id="treat" >Treatments By Surgeon/Clinic</button>
              <button id="enqstats">Enquiry and New Patient Stats</button>
              <button id="embassy">Special Embassy Patients</button>
              <button id="notreat">No Treatment/Not Suitable By Clinic</button>
              <button id="bookclinic">Bookings By Clinic</button>
              <button id="bookstats">Bookings Summary</button>
              <button id="surgnopre">Surgery Booked with no Pre Op Assess done</button>
              <button id="prebook">Pre Op Booking Analysis</button>
              <button id="bookfirst">Bookings By Date First Booked</button>
              <button id="bookappt">Bookings By Appointment Date</button>
              <button id="bookdet">Booking By Appointment Date (Detail)</button>
              <button id="pricebreak">Price Break Analysis</button>
              <button id="surgpay">Surgeon Payments</button>
          </div>
        </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution by chance.  It seems to work

In my html the `<metadata name="viewport" ...` I should add `shrink-to-fit=no`

So the whole thing becomes

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I found the solution in this article https://bitsofco.de/ios-safari-and-shrink-to-fit/